# Adjusting tabularx to textwidth

Tags: tables, tabularx

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {X||XXXXXXXX}
    Dokument & WM & Geschäft & Sieg & Adidas & feiert & Europa & Macron & Wahlsieg\\
    \hline
    \hline
    1  & 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2
    \end{tabularx}   
\end{center}
```

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqxQK.png)

I wanted to adjust a table to the `textwidth` but the formatting did not work, the words overlap each other as you can see in the added image.

I expected to solve the problem with tabularx but it didn't work.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Apparently column headers are wider than column widths. BTW, the question title is about `longtable` but your code sniped uae `tabularx` ... what is your problem, actually?

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. I did not meant to confuse with using the term longtable , i thought  it refers to the problem of wanting to adjust a 'long' table to textwidth (which is actually my problem). How can I avoid overlapping of the words but keeping the textwidth. (or making the words fit into the column)

Comment: We can't help you if we not know anything about your document. Please (agaib) provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) that we can see what you doing (with table).

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that your document setup doesn't allow hyphenation of the cell contents in the header row of the `tabularx` environment -- even though it's clearly needed.

To fix this, I suggest you (a) load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1` to allow LaTeX to hyphenate words that contain Umlauts and other accented characters, (b) load the `babel` package with the option `ngerman` to load the language-appropriate hyphenation rules, (c) decrease the value of `\tabcolsep` (the parameter that determines the amount of intercolumn whitespace) in order to increase the available usable width of the nine columns and, most importantly, (d) modify the `X` column type to allow hyhenation of the *first* -- and, in this case, only -- word in a cell. (Actually, step (d) isn't needed if you compile the document under LuaLaTEX.)

I would also like to encourage you to think about whether left-alignment or centering of the cell contents is more appropriate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macros
%% The '\hspace{0pt}' particles trick LaTeX into allowing 
%% hyphenation of the *actual* first word of a cell:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % left-align
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}   % center

\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next two instructions
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}    % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"

%% First version: perform left-alignment of cell contents
\noindent % <-- important
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{} L | *{9}{L} @{}}
Dokument & WM & Geschäft & Sieg & Adidas & feiert & Europa & Macron & Wahlsieg\\
\hline
1 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}  

%% Second version: perform centering of cell contents
\bigskip
\noindent % <-- important
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{} C | *{9}{C} @{}}
Dokument & WM & Geschäft & Sieg & Adidas & feiert & Europa & Macron & Wahlsieg\\
\hline
1 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}  
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful advice, i've just fixed the problem.